# Perform join based on near by Dates

Tags: sql-server, date, join, kql

I have the following two tables and want to join based on the near by dates (most recent available date).

I can't use Delete/Inserts because I need to convert this into KQL(Kusto). Please help.

Code snippet:

```
drop table if exists #table1
drop table if exists #table2
create table #table1 ([date] date, val int)
create table #table2 ([date] date, discount int)

insert into #table1 ([date], val) values ('1/26/2010', 10)
insert into #table1 ([date], val) values ('1/25/2010', 9)
insert into #table1 ([date], val) values ('1/24/2010', 8)
insert into #table1 ([date], val) values ('1/24/2010', 9)
insert into #table1 ([date], val) values ('1/23/2010', 7)
insert into #table1 ([date], val) values ('1/22/2010', 10)
insert into #table1 ([date], val) values ('1/19/2010', 11)

insert into #table2 ([date], discount) values ('1/26/2010', 2)
insert into #table2 ([date], discount) values ('1/23/2010', 1)
insert into #table2 ([date], discount) values ('1/20/2010', 0)

Desired Result:
date    val date    discount
2010-01-26  10  2010-01-26  2
2010-01-23  7   2010-01-23  1
2010-01-19  11  2010-01-20  0
```

Comment: Desired result:
date val date discount
2010-01-26 10 2010-01-26 2
2010-01-23 7 2010-01-23 1
2010-01-19 11 2010-01-20 0

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into the question.

Comment: So you are trying to match every row in `table2` to the nearest date before or after in `table1`? And what happens if you have two dates equidistant, take the earlier or later?

Comment: Take earlier when two dates equidistant

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer but any efficient method that you can suggest are welcome:

```
select * from (
Select t2.date,
t2.discount,t1.date as date2, t1.val ,row_number() over( partition by t2.date order by t1.date desc) rn
from #table2 t2
inner join #table1 t1 on t1.date <= t2.date) t
where t.rn = 1
```